# Add a Graphics JComponent using a GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I'm looking for a way to place a JComponent that uses Graphics alongside other JComponents such as JRadioButton.

Therefore, I tried to build a GridBagConstraints in my JPanel to allow easy placement. But I can't figure out how to place the graphic component on the grid using a correct constraint. If I add the constraint, a very small portion of the graphic appears.

My code below:

```
public class Interface extends JFrame{
    private Visualization v;
    private GridBagConstraints constraints=new GridBagConstraints();
    private JRadioButton temperature,pluviometry;

    public Interface(Visualization v){
        this.setTitle("Pluviometry Data Viewer");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.v=v;

        //this.getContentPane().add(v);
        //this.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        constraints.gridx=0;
        constraints.gridy=0;
        constraints.gridheight=(int)v.getPreferredSize().getSize().getHeight();
        constraints.gridwidth=(int)v.getPreferredSize().getSize().getWidth();
        //constraints.fill=BOTH;

        this.add(v);
        //this.add(new JRadioButton("Temperature", true),constraints);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
       this.setSize(new Dimension(540, 360));
    }
}


public class Visualization extends JComponent {
    Data data;

    private int y_axis=210;
    private int x_axis=450;
    public Visualization(Data d){
        this.data=d;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        int width=getWidth();
        int height=getHeight();

        g.setColor(new Color(255, 78, 23));
        g.drawLine(50, 20, 50, 230);
        g.drawLine(50, 230, 500, 230);
        for(int i=100;i<=500;i+=50){
            g.drawLine(i, 230, i, 240);
        }
        for(int i=180;i>0;i-=40){
            g.drawLine(50, i, 40, i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        return new Dimension(200,100);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You've commented out your call to `setLayout(new GridBagLayout());`. Please understand that GridBagConstraints are worse than meaningless unless they are used to add components to a GridBagLayout-using container. I say "worse than meaningless" because use of them is misleading, and with other layout managers can lead to unpredictable layouts or even exceptions being thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of small issues...

1. You never actually use a `GridBagLayout`
2. You never supply the `GridBagConstraints` to the container when you add the `Visualization`
3. The `preferredSize` of `Visualization` doesn't match what you are actually rendering
4. You should try and call `setVisible` last, once you've established the UI
5. Calling `setSize` on a `JFrame` isn't highly recommended
6. `gridwidth` and `gridheight` are measured in cells within the context of the `GridBagLayout`, not pixels...

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestGUI extends JFrame {

    private Visualization v;
    private GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JRadioButton temperature, pluviometry;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                Visualization v = new Visualization();
                TestGUI frame = new TestGUI(v);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
    }

    public TestGUI(Visualization v) {
        this.setTitle("Pluviometry Data Viewer");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.v = v;

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        constraints.gridx = 0;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        add(new JRadioButton("Cool stuff"), constraints);

        constraints.gridx = 1;
        constraints.gridy = 0;
        constraints.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        this.add(v, constraints);
        //this.add(new JRadioButton("Temperature", true),constraints);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class Visualization extends JComponent {

        private int y_axis = 210;
        private int x_axis = 450;

        public Visualization() {
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            g.setColor(new Color(255, 78, 23));
            g.drawLine(50, 20, 50, 230);
            g.drawLine(50, 230, 500, 230);
            for (int i = 100; i <= 500; i += 50) {
                g.drawLine(i, 230, i, 240);
            }
            for (int i = 180; i > 0; i -= 40) {
                g.drawLine(50, i, 40, i);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(500 + 50, 230 + 50);
        }
    }
}
```